# Unity 2D - How to place obstacle in Running game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I finish making running game. But I placed obstacle like this :

[image]

This way makes phone frozen often. So I make a prefeb is made of obstacle object like this :

[image]

[image]

I want to use function `SetActive(bool)` to appear/disappear obstacle. Finally, How it works is My runner is at a standstill and background, obstacle, coin, juwel is moved. But My creator script has a big problem.

My Prolem :

[image]

As you see, This code create blank(red box) between two obstacle prefebs. I can't find problem. Plz help me...

Creator Script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CsPartCreator : MonoBehaviour {
    int count = 1;
    float timer = 0.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++)//set Deactive all object excluding first object (Because This object is watched at first.)
            transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer > 5f && count < 23)//every 5 seconds and count is smaller than the number of prefeb
        {
            transform.GetChild(count).gameObject.SetActive(true);//
            count++;
            timer = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Hierarchy :

[image]

Comment: Is first obstacle placed in  0,0,0 in prefab?

Comment: @SteveJobs No, it isn't.

Comment: You already have placed those prefabs in scene , And what you want to do is set those prefabs activated as player walks , Right ? , Or are those prefabs Instantiated and placed by another script ?

Comment: @SteveJobs Yes! I wanna that:)

Comment: There is rather very simple way you can activate deactivate those objects,
Set a tag to those preafbs called "Obstacle" or something, And Check if they overlap a Spehere or , If a line hit them , As player moves.

Comment: Oh, I understand until `Set a tag to those preafbs called "Obstacle" or something`. I'm sorry, Can you describe detail for me?

Comment: Add a Layer for Obstacle, 
Add a script to player , And in that script's fixed update function  you can check if  CircleOverlap with "ObstacleLayer" , If overlap you can activate.

void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Range Check
        
        var  obstacleInRange= Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position, rangeRaidus, obstacleLayer); 
    }

Comment: If that sounds complex , There is a very easy way, I will post it as an answer. If it doesn't work Comment ,

Comment: Oh, I think that.... Plz write to answer! I want to listen your answer:)

Comment: Did it solve your problem ?

Comment: @SteveJobs No, It didn't.... It's same.

Comment: Haha, I think I got what's the issue here.  Adjust the Z value of that missing Prefab. I think YOu have a set a negative Z value or something,   Check that, If you are using Sorting layers check that too

Comment: @SteveJobs SetActive(true) is working only Part0, Part3! Why is that...?

Comment: Check if all obstacles correctly orderered in Hirachy 
Part0, Part1, Part2, Part3  like that. 

Let me know if those are in correct order,  IF you can post a snapshot.

Comment: @SteveJobs OK, I add it!

Comment: Are obstacle gameobjects set to active in scene ?

Comment: Yes. I test code, Problem is in the `var toActivate = obstacles.Where(x => x.transform.position.x > transform.position.x && x.transform.position.x < transform.position.x + 10).ToList();
        foreach (GameObject go in toActivate)
        {
            go.SetActive(true);
            obstacles.Remove(go);
        }`

Comment: Ahh , I thought you are still using   // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer > 5f && count < 23)//every 5 seconds and count is smaller than the number of prefeb
        {
            transform.GetChild(count).gameObject.SetActive(true);//
            count++;
            timer = 0;
        }
    } , That code :

Comment: If you are using that code,  Please user "player.transform.position.x" instead of "transform.position.x" , Try that and let me know.

set player to "Player" tag, and then add a variable "private GameObject player; "

and use "int i = 0; " instead of "int i = 1" in loops

Comment: i have update my answer check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think , That missing prefab's Z value is more negative than background , Or you have used a sorting layer which is set to be behind background.

And Check if all obstacle gameobjects correctly orderered in Hirachy Part0, Part1, Part2, Part3 like that. Let me know if those are in correct order

Please check that :)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CsPartCreator : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject player;

    float timer = 0.0f;

    private List<GameObject> obstacles;

    void Awake()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
        obstacles = new List<GameObject>();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)//set Deactive all object excluding first object (Because This object is watched at first.)
        {
            obstacles.Add(transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
            transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(false);

        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (obstacles == null || obstacles.Count() == 0)
            return;

        var toActivate = obstacles.Where(x => x.transform.position.x > transform.position.x && x.transform.position.x < transform.position.x + 10).ToList(); // +10 is the range
        foreach (GameObject go in toActivate)
        {
            go.SetActive(true);
            obstacles.Remove(go);
        }
    }
}
```

Set player gameobject to "Player" tag as in  image below
[image]

Comment: Still Part0 and Part3 are active... But thank you for detail explain and help!

Comment: if it's possible you can send me a copy of your project if that's not too big,  I will investigate the issue and will  let you know what exactly is happening.

Comment: Oh, This time, All Part is deactive when I replace `transform.position.x` to `player.transform.position.x`

Comment: Does it not activate gameobjects when player walking toward ?

Comment: How can I send my project to you? Email?

Comment: If its' too big for an email , you can share it on Google Drive.

Comment: I send Email to you!

Comment: That didn't work because in fact runner is not moving  but the background. That's the issue. I'll fix that.

Comment: Ahh , Just fixed it ,

Comment: I've sent you updated project,  Please check and let me know. If it works ,I hop you will accept my answer :)

Comment: Wow.... Steve, Thank you so much. I'm really happy and surprised! Game isn't frozen and is pleasant! I think I've learned a lot. Thanks to you:)